# how to add list items in listbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

i am trying to add list items in listbox by the below code
if i am wrong please correct me ..
the below code is giving weird output.

```
Try
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
        con = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        sqlstr = "select * from partyinfo "
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con)
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        lbpartylink.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        lbpartyunlink.ValueMember = "partyid"
        lbpartyunlink.DisplayMember = "partyname"
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error found")
    End Try
```

Comment: What are the weird results that you are getting?  Can you be more specific?  On a side-note, why create the `DataSet` at all if you never use it?

Answer (score 0):

my fault i wrote

```
lbpartylink.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

in place of
    lbpartyulink.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)